# How would you say 'the past ____'? (i.e. the past 'hour', the past 'day)

Tags: time

I've been wondering how to say 'I spent the past [time frame] [insert action]'. For example, "I spent the past hour studying Japanese". Would it be translated to something like...

> 日本語の勉強は最近の一時間が全かかりました

...or would it be something like...

> 日本語の勉強はついさっきの一時間が全かかりました。

OR! Would the sentence structure be completely different?

I'm sorry if this has already been asked before, but I can't seem to find anything concerning this type of phrasing.

Answer (score 6):

By far the most common way of expressing that would be to use 「この」 as in 「この１時間」、「この１ヶ月（間）」、「この１年（間）」, etc.

Some natural ways to say  "I spent the past hour studying Japanese." for us native speakers are:

> 「日本語の勉強にこの１時間をかけました。」
>
> 「この１時間を日本語の勉強に[充]{あ}てました。」
>
> 「この１時間をかけて日本語を勉強しました。」
>
> 「この１時間をかけて日本語の勉強をしました。」

Comment: Do you think that you could explain (or link a grammar post) the use of に in your first example?

Answer (score 2):

How about ここ in this case?

```
「ここ一時間ぐらいずっと勉強してた。」
「ここ数日ずっと忙しかった。」
「ここ２週間海外にいた。」
```